# How to program an NFT with multiple layers?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, nft, async

NFTs with multiple layers are being made now. e.g. an NFT made of different images sometimes owned by different artists.

These NFTs are referred to as programmable NFTs, async NFTs and or dynamic NFTs.

The base NFT would be an ERC1155, this would be the blank slate which you could add more ERC1155 pieces to. These could also be layers if the layers below it were transparent.

Would this work?

```
BaseContract.sol:

contract layeredNFT is ERC1155 {
  using baseLayer for uint256;

  struct NFT {
    //Each layer is a ERC1155 token with a different transparent PNG image.
    uint256 layer1;
    uint256 layer2;
    uint256 layer3;
  }

LayerContract.sol:

contract layer is ERC1155 { 

This token's URI points to the metadata with image..

}
```

Comment: This is a question about which question to ask. Too meta. Please get concrete.

Comment: There's EIP 3589 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3589 it is just a draft, but you can use as a base for an NFT.